# "does not have a class type" error

Tags: c++

**Player** class:-

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class Player : public sf::Drawable, sf::Transformable
{
    public:
        Player(int indexWd, int indexHi);
        bool load();
};
```

**Game** class :-

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "Player.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Game
{
    public:
        Game();        
        Player player(int indWd, int indHi);
        void load();
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

**Inside Game cpp file** :-

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{

}

void Game::load()
{
    player(world.getIndexWd(), world.getIndexHi());
    player.load(); //gives error

}
```

at player.load() in the above method, compiler is giving the following error :-

> error: '((Game*)this)->Game::player' does not have class type|

Why is this error happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared a member function called `player`, and you're trying to use that as if it were a variable.

I'm guessing that it's supposed to be a data member:

```
Player player;
```

initialised in the `load` function:

```
player = Player(world.getIndexWd(), world.getIndexHi());
player.load();
```

Although this won't work since it doesn't have a default constructor, so must be initialised in the constructor:

```
Game::Game() : player(world.getIndexWd(), world.getIndexHi()) {}
```

which will only work if `world` has been initialised at this point.

Comment: player = Player(world.getIndexWd(), world.getIndexHi());

player.load();


I did this in the load function but it is not working. It is giving the following error:-

error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)

Comment: @rkj: Did you also change `player` to be a variable, like I said? Assuming it's supposed to be a variable, of course. I'm just speculating since the code you posted doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes I did, change it to Player player;. But now it is giving this error :-
     error: no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'

Comment: @rkj: Did you read my answer? Either give it a default constructor, or initialise it in the `Game` constructor.

Comment: Why can't I just define it in the load function? Also why do I need to provide another constructor when there is already one defined?

Comment: @rkj: All class members are initialised by the constructor - that's the job of a constructor, which you're trying to subvert with your strange second-stage initialisation function. If you don't include them in the initialiser list, they're default-initialised, for which they need a default constructor. So you'll either have to provide a default constructor, so it can be default-initialised by the `Game` constructor, or include it in the initialiser list of the `Game` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite as:

```
void Game::load()
{
    Player p = this->player(world.getIndexWd(), world.getIndexHi());
    p.load();
}
```

`player` is a member function in current class and you can not apply `.load` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You did not define your function

```
Player player(int indWd, int indHi);
```

in your .cpp file.

Also you need to either make it static in your `Player` class, or use an object to call it.

```
Player p = player(world.getIndexWd(), world.getIndexHi());
p.load();
```

Possible would also be

```
player(world.getIndexWd(), world.getIndexHi()).load();
```

but I would not recommend using it, as your `Player` object will be destroyed afterwards.